# javascript form validation_error in if condition

Tags: javascript, validation, spring-mvc

I have my form in Spring MVC into which I need to apply java script validations as well. The code is given below.

```js
function validate_form() {
  valid = true;
  var fname = document.myform.firstname.value;

  if (fname == "") {
    document.getElementById('fname_error').innerHTML = "enter the first name";
    valid = false;
  }

  return valid;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <form:form action="done" method="post" modelAttribute="student" name="myform" onsubmit="return validate_form()">

    <p>First name:</p>
    <form:input type="text" path="firstname" name="firstname" />
    <p id="fname_error"></p>

    <input type="submit" value="Sumbit">

  </form:form>

</body>

</html>
```

Here the java script code executes, but the if condition does not executes. Is this problem need to be solved using the controller class? Please help me in this matter.

thank you.

Comment: Can you check the console log to see if there is any error?

Comment: insert alert("["+fname+"]") after you get its value, and check whether it is the value expected.  maybe its some spaces.

Comment: @VincentZhang - I have included the alert after the variable declaration. But it does not appear, which means the data is not passed. Is this issue is due to the Spring MVC framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are adding `:form` there which was not necessary.

Here is the running code:

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>

<form action="done" method="post"  modelAttribute="student" name="myform" onsubmit="return validate_form()">

        <p>First name:</p>
    <input type="text" path="firstname" name="firstname" />
        <p id="fname_error"></p>


    <input type="submit" value="Sumbit" >

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate_form(){
        valid = true;
        var fname = document.myform.firstname.value;

      if(fname == ""){
            document.getElementById('fname_error').innerHTML = "enter the first name";
            valid = false;
        }

        return valid;

    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @swetanshkumar